# Is there any way to optimize the lateral flatten json query in Snowflake? My query is taking too much time to execute

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, flatten, lateral

I have json with nested arrays data vary for different jsons. I am putting my json parsing code and sample json file here. Query only got slow when there are many objects for rows tags as you can see below for this json query executes within a minute but when I have 100 objects then it will take up to 50 minutes. you can see the json below

```
    {
  "page_desktop_image": {
    "responseAggregationType": "byPage",
    "rows": [
      {
        "clicks": 5,
        "ctr": 0.003048780487804878,
        "impressions": 1640,
        "keys": [
          "abc"
        ],
        "position": 10.207317073170731
      },
      {
        "clicks": 2,
        "ctr": 0.010638297872340425,
        "impressions": 188,
        "keys": [
          "abc"
        ],
        "position": 28.324468085106382
      },
      {
        "clicks": 0,
        "ctr": 0,
        "impressions": 4,
        "keys": [
          "abc"
        ],
        "position": 237.5
      }
    ]
  },
  "page_desktop_video": {
    "responseAggregationType": "byPage",
    "rows": [
      {
        "clicks": 1,
        "ctr": 0.038461538461538464,
        "impressions": 26,
        "keys": [
          "abc"
        ],
        "position": 4.5
      },
      {
        "clicks": 0,
        "ctr": 0,
        "impressions": 19,
        "keys": [
          "abc"
        ],
        "position": 6.947368421052632
      }
    ]
  },
  "page_desktop_web": {
    "responseAggregationType": "byPage",
    "rows": [
      {
        "clicks": 8578,
        "ctr": 0.28393631458740193,
        "impressions": 30211,
        "keys": [
          "abc"
        ],
        "position": 1.7217900764622156
      },
      {
        "clicks": 0,
        "ctr": 0,
        "impressions": 22,
        "keys": [
          "abc"
        ],
        "position": 12.318181818181818
      }
    ]
  },
  "page_mobile_image": {
    "responseAggregationType": "byPage",
    "rows": [
      {
        "clicks": 3,
        "ctr": 0.028037383177570093,
        "impressions": 107,
        "keys": [
          "abc"
        ],
        "position": 17.018691588785046
      },
      {
        "clicks": 0,
        "ctr": 0,
        "impressions": 37,
        "keys": [
          "abcx"
        ],
        "position": 38.4054054054054
      }
    ]
  },
  "page_mobile_video": {
    "responseAggregationType": "byPage",
    "rows": [
      {
        "clicks": 2,
        "ctr": 0.05128205128205128,
        "impressions": 39,
        "keys": [
          "abc"
        ],
        "position": 6.487179487179487
      },
      {
        "clicks": 0,
        "ctr": 0,
        "impressions": 64,
        "keys": [
          "abc"
        ],
        "position": 4.3125
      }
    ]
  },
  "page_mobile_web": {
    "responseAggregationType": "byPage",
    "rows": [
      {
        "clicks": 3604,
        "ctr": 0.1579385599719532,
        "impressions": 22819,
        "keys": [
          "abc"
        ],
        "position": 2.3936193522941407
      },
            {
        "clicks": 0,
        "ctr": 0,
        "impressions": 12,
        "keys": [
          "abc"
        ],
        "position": 6.583333333333333
      }
    ]
  },
  "page_tablet_image": {
    "responseAggregationType": "byPage",
    "rows": [
      {
        "clicks": 1,
        "ctr": 0.005649717514124294,
        "impressions": 177,
        "keys": [
          "abc"
        ],
        "position": 5.112994350282486
      },
            {
        "clicks": 0,
        "ctr": 0,
        "impressions": 6,
        "keys": [
          "abc"
        ],
        "position": 33.5
      }
    ]
  },
  "page_tablet_video": {
    "responseAggregationType": "byPage",
    "rows": [
      {
        "clicks": 1,
        "ctr": 0.1,
        "impressions": 10,
        "keys": [
          "abc"
        ],
        "position": 18.7
      },
           {
        "clicks": 0,
        "ctr": 0,
        "impressions": 1,
        "keys": [
          "abc"
        ],
        "position": 10
      }
    ]
  },
  "page_tablet_web": {
    "responseAggregationType": "byPage",
    "rows": [
      {
        "clicks": 639,
        "ctr": 0.2729602733874413,
        "impressions": 2341,
        "keys": [
          "abc"
        ],
        "position": 1.5262708244340026
      },
     {
        "clicks": 0,
        "ctr": 0,
        "impressions": 27,
        "keys": [
          "abc"
        ],
        "position": 60.55555555555556
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and this is my json parsing code:

```
    SELECT 
                 JSON_FILE:page_desktop_image:responseAggregationType::String as responseAggregationType_desk_image
                   , r_desk_image.value:clicks as clicks_desk_image
                   , r_desk_image.value:ctr as ctr_desk_image
                   , r_desk_image.value:impressions as impressions_desk_image
                   , array_to_string(r_desk_image.value:keys , '') as keys_desk_image
                   , r_desk_image.value:position as position_desk_image
                   ,JSON_FILE:page_desktop_video:responseAggregationType::String as responseAggregationType_desk_video
                   , r_desk_video.value:clicks as clicks_desk_video
                   , r_desk_video.value:ctr as ctr_desk_video
                   , r_desk_video.value:impressions as impressions_desk_video
                   , array_to_string(r_desk_video.value:keys,'') as keys_desk_video
                   , r_desk_video.value:position as position_desk_video
                   ,JSON_FILE:page_desktop_web:responseAggregationType::String as responseAggregationType_desk_web
                   , r_desk_web.value:clicks as clicks_desk_web
                   , r_desk_web.value:ctr as ctr_desk_web
                   , r_desk_web.value:impressions as impressions_desk_web
                   , array_to_string(r_desk_web.value:keys,'') as keys_desk_web
                   , r_desk_web.value:position as position_desk_web
                   ,JSON_FILE:page_mobile_image:responseAggregationType::String as responseAggregationType_mob_image
                   , r_mob_image.value:clicks as clicks_mob_image
                   , r_mob_image.value:ctr as ctr_mob_image
                   , r_mob_image.value:impressions as impressions__mob_image
                   , array_to_string(r_mob_image.value:keys,'') as keys_mob_image
                   , r_mob_image.value:position as position_mob_image
                   ,JSON_FILE:page_mobile_video:responseAggregationType::String as responseAggregationType_mob_video
                   , r_mob_video.value:clicks as clicks_mob_video
                   , r_mob_video.value:ctr as ctr_mob_video
                   , r_mob_video.value:impressions as impressions_mob_video
                   , array_to_string(r_mob_video.value:keys,'') as keys_mob_video
                   , r_mob_video.value:position as position_mob_video
                   ,JSON_FILE:page_mobile_web:responseAggregationType::String as responseAggregationType_mob_web
                   , r_mob_web.value:clicks as clicks_mob_web
                   , r_mob_web.value:ctr as ctr_mob_web
                   , r_mob_web.value:impressions as impressions_mob_web
                   , array_to_string(r_mob_web.value:keys,'') as keys_mob_web
                   , r_mob_web.value:position as position_mob_web
                   ,JSON_FILE:page_tablet_image:responseAggregationType::String as responseAggregationType_tab_image
                   , r_tab_image.value:clicks as clicks_tab_image
                   , r_tab_image.value:ctr as ctr_tab_image
                   , r_tab_image.value:impressions as impressions_tab_image
                   , array_to_string(r_tab_image.value:keys,'') as keys_tab_image
                   , r_tab_image.value:position as position_tab_image
                   ,JSON_FILE:page_tablet_video:responseAggregationType::String as responseAggregationType_tab_video
                   , r_tab_video.value:clicks as clicks_tab_video
                   , r_tab_video.value:ctr as ctr_tab_video
                   , r_tab_video.value:impressions as impressions_tab_video
                   , array_to_string(r_tab_video.value:keys,'') as keys_tab_video
                   , r_tab_video.value:position as position_tab_video
                   ,JSON_FILE:page_tablet_web:responseAggregationType::String as responseAggregationType_tab_web
                   , r_tab_web.value:clicks as clicks_tab_web
                   , r_tab_web.value:ctr as ctr_tab_web
                   , r_tab_web.value:impressions as impressions_tab_web
                   , array_to_string(r_tab_web.value:keys ,'') as keys_tab_web
                   , r_tab_web.value:position as position_tab_web
              from GSC_JSONS
                   ,lateral flatten(input => JSON_FILE:page_desktop_image:rows) as r_desk_image
                   ,lateral flatten(input => JSON_FILE:page_desktop_video:rows) as r_desk_video
                   ,lateral flatten(input => JSON_FILE:page_desktop_web:rows) as r_desk_web
                   ,lateral flatten(input => JSON_FILE:page_mobile_image:rows) as r_mob_image
                   ,lateral flatten(input => JSON_FILE:page_mobile_video:rows) as r_mob_video
                   ,lateral flatten(input => JSON_FILE:page_mobile_web:rows) as r_mob_web
                   ,lateral flatten(input => JSON_FILE:page_tablet_image:rows) as r_tab_image
                   ,lateral flatten(input => JSON_FILE:page_tablet_video:rows) as r_tab_video
                   ,lateral flatten(input => JSON_FILE:page_tablet_web:rows) as r_tab_web
```

If anyone knows the workaround then please let me know. I know why it is slow because it makes cross joins for each object but I want to execute it faster.

Comment: this seems strange, you have mostly 2 rows in each object, but you are wanting the 3*2^8 rows from this? That seems rather odd to want all permutations. But I would think it should be faster to make your 9 flattens inside 9 CTE's and then join those, thus the transform steps like the `array_to_string(r_tab_image.value:keys,'')` is done just once.

Comment: You didn't get my point. I just want to speed up my query for hundreds of objects.

Comment: Given your SQL as you have written it, I am sure I know how to make it faster. I just think it's bad SQL, so was first checking how this toy example is playing out is actually how you intend for it to work. I gave you a hint, but you will also note, I did not provide a answer, that is done by the "answer box" I asked you a clarify question. Which you have not addressed.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you make a materialized view on top of the flattened output.
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/views-materialized.html

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW myview AS
SELECT 
    JSON_FILE:page_desktop_image:responseAggregationType::String as responseAggregationType_desk_image
    , r_desk_image.value:clicks as clicks_desk_image
    , r_desk_image.value:ctr as ctr_desk_image
    , r_desk_image.value:impressions as impressions_desk_image
    , array_to_string(r_desk_image.value:keys , '') as keys_desk_image
    , r_desk_image.value:position as position_desk_image
    ,JSON_FILE:page_desktop_video:responseAggregationType::String as responseAggregationType_desk_video
    , r_desk_video.value:clicks as clicks_desk_video
    , r_desk_video.value:ctr as ctr_desk_video
    , r_desk_video.value:impressions as impressions_desk_video
    , array_to_string(r_desk_video.value:keys,'') as keys_desk_video
    , r_desk_video.value:position as position_desk_video
    ,JSON_FILE:page_desktop_web:responseAggregationType::String as responseAggregationType_desk_web
    , r_desk_web.value:clicks as clicks_desk_web
    , r_desk_web.value:ctr as ctr_desk_web
    , r_desk_web.value:impressions as impressions_desk_web
    , array_to_string(r_desk_web.value:keys,'') as keys_desk_web
    , r_desk_web.value:position as position_desk_web
    ,JSON_FILE:page_mobile_image:responseAggregationType::String as responseAggregationType_mob_image
    , r_mob_image.value:clicks as clicks_mob_image
    , r_mob_image.value:ctr as ctr_mob_image
    , r_mob_image.value:impressions as impressions__mob_image
    , array_to_string(r_mob_image.value:keys,'') as keys_mob_image
    , r_mob_image.value:position as position_mob_image
    ,JSON_FILE:page_mobile_video:responseAggregationType::String as responseAggregationType_mob_video
    , r_mob_video.value:clicks as clicks_mob_video
    , r_mob_video.value:ctr as ctr_mob_video
    , r_mob_video.value:impressions as impressions_mob_video
    , array_to_string(r_mob_video.value:keys,'') as keys_mob_video
    , r_mob_video.value:position as position_mob_video
    ,JSON_FILE:page_mobile_web:responseAggregationType::String as responseAggregationType_mob_web
    , r_mob_web.value:clicks as clicks_mob_web
    , r_mob_web.value:ctr as ctr_mob_web
    , r_mob_web.value:impressions as impressions_mob_web
    , array_to_string(r_mob_web.value:keys,'') as keys_mob_web
    , r_mob_web.value:position as position_mob_web
    ,JSON_FILE:page_tablet_image:responseAggregationType::String as responseAggregationType_tab_image
    , r_tab_image.value:clicks as clicks_tab_image
    , r_tab_image.value:ctr as ctr_tab_image
    , r_tab_image.value:impressions as impressions_tab_image
    , array_to_string(r_tab_image.value:keys,'') as keys_tab_image
    , r_tab_image.value:position as position_tab_image
    ,JSON_FILE:page_tablet_video:responseAggregationType::String as responseAggregationType_tab_video
    , r_tab_video.value:clicks as clicks_tab_video
    , r_tab_video.value:ctr as ctr_tab_video
    , r_tab_video.value:impressions as impressions_tab_video
    , array_to_string(r_tab_video.value:keys,'') as keys_tab_video
    , r_tab_video.value:position as position_tab_video
    ,JSON_FILE:page_tablet_web:responseAggregationType::String as responseAggregationType_tab_web
    , r_tab_web.value:clicks as clicks_tab_web
    , r_tab_web.value:ctr as ctr_tab_web
    , r_tab_web.value:impressions as impressions_tab_web
    , array_to_string(r_tab_web.value:keys ,'') as keys_tab_web
    , r_tab_web.value:position as position_tab_web
FROM gsc_jsons
    ,lateral flatten(input => JSON_FILE:page_desktop_image:rows) as r_desk_image
    ,lateral flatten(input => JSON_FILE:page_desktop_video:rows) as r_desk_video
    ,lateral flatten(input => JSON_FILE:page_desktop_web:rows) as r_desk_web
    ,lateral flatten(input => JSON_FILE:page_mobile_image:rows) as r_mob_image
    ,lateral flatten(input => JSON_FILE:page_mobile_video:rows) as r_mob_video
    ,lateral flatten(input => JSON_FILE:page_mobile_web:rows) as r_mob_web
    ,lateral flatten(input => JSON_FILE:page_tablet_image:rows) as r_tab_image
    ,lateral flatten(input => JSON_FILE:page_tablet_video:rows) as r_tab_video
    ,lateral flatten(input => JSON_FILE:page_tablet_web:rows) as r_tab_web
```